# Get value in spinner when click another spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to create two spinners.

For example:
(this is list in Spinner1)

```
Category A
Category B
Category C
```

When I select category A in spinner1, spinner2 will display the value of category A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create 2 `Spinner` in your XML.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Then you have to declare variables for your `Spinner`.

```
final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
```

Now you need a `String[]` for each `Spinner`, but you want to change the value of one spinner so you have to create a `String[]` for each case.

```
    String[] categories = new String[] {
            "Category A", "Category B", "Category C"
    };
    String[] category_a_values = new String[] {
            "Value 1 from category a", "Value 2 from category a", "Value 3 from category a"
    };
    String[] category_b_values = new String[] {
            "Value 1 from category b", "Value 2 from category b", "Value 3 from category b"
    };
    String[] category_c_values = new String[] {
            "Value 1 from category c", "Value 2 from category c", "Value 3 from category c"
    };
```

The `String[]` *categories* is for *spinner1* and the other for *spinner2*.

Now we need an `ArrayAdapter` for each `String[]`.

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> categories_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> category_a_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_a_values);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> category_b_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_b_values);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> category_c_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_c_values);
```

Here we set the `ArrayAdapter` to *spinner1*.

```
spinner1.setAdapter(categories_adapter);
```

Then you change the `ArrayAdapter` of *spinner2* if another value of *spinner1* was selected.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    spinner2.setAdapter(category_a_adapter);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    spinner2.setAdapter(category_b_adapter);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    spinner2.setAdapter(category_c_adapter);
                    break;

                    default:


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

## The whole code looks like this

```
final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);


    String[] categories = new String[] {
            "Category A", "Category B", "Category C"
    };
    String[] category_a_values = new String[] {
            "Value 1 from category a", "Value 2 from category a", "Value 3 from category a"
    };
    String[] category_b_values = new String[] {
            "Value 1 from category b", "Value 2 from category b", "Value 3 from category b"
    };
    String[] category_c_values = new String[] {
            "Value 1 from category c", "Value 2 from category c", "Value 3 from category c"
    };
    final ArrayAdapter<String> categories_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> category_a_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_a_values);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> category_b_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_b_values);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> category_c_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, category_c_values);

    spinner1.setAdapter(categories_adapter);

    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    spinner2.setAdapter(category_a_adapter);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    spinner2.setAdapter(category_b_adapter);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    spinner2.setAdapter(category_c_adapter);
                    break;

                    default:


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Spinner spinner1 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_1);
Spinner spinner2 = findViewById(R.id.spinner_2);    

String[] arraySpinner = new String[] {
        "Category A", "Category B", "Category C"
};

String[] arraySpinner2 = new String[] {
        "Category A value", "Category B value", "Category C value"
};

ArrayAdapter<String> adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);

adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner1.setAdapter(adp1);

ArrayAdapter<String> adp2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                          android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner2);

adp2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adp2);

spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){ 

        spinner2.setSelection(spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


    }
});
```

I have not tested this code yet. I will test later when I get the time.